# SSRS 2008 R2 "Error: Subreport could not be shown"

Tags: ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, subreport, bids

I have a stand-alone report that works no problem.  I have added it as a subreport and linked up all of the parameters, but when I run the report in BIDS I get the error message in the subject of this post.

I can deploy the report and I am able to see the subreport when I log into the SSRS web interface.

It would make things easier if I could do the report building/debugging through BIDS.

Any insight/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/74e51434-1d14-4fb1-9b1c-1a394c187b2f).  Once I have a feedback link I will update this post.

Hi,

Thanks for finding this question about shared datasource/dataset. Currently, there is no way to Preview the subreport with shared datasource/dataset in BIDS. I would suggest you submit a feedback at http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback and hope microsoft correct it in the next release of SSRS service pack.

thanks,
Jerry